# Copy/Paste HTML From One Page To Another Loses CSS Reference

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2012

I am creating a web site and need to copy certain HTML from one page to another (rather than re-write it. Take this table for example:

I copy (from Page1.aspx)...

```
<table class="InfoBox">
  <tr>
    <td class="InfoBoxTopHeader">Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="InfoBoxContent"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then I paste (into Page2.aspx) and get....

```
<table class="InfoBox">
  <tr>
    <td class="InfoBoxTopHeader">Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="auto-style1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It takes the CSS from my CSS file, inserts it in the top of the APSX file and names it `auto-style1` in this case only for `InfoBoxContent` but it could be all sometimes.  It is driving me nuts.

I am using Visual Studio 2012.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Could you just use a master page? Then you wouldn't need to worry about copying styling...

Comment: @Tim Yes I guess I should do but to be honest I have never been involved in page styling and layout really and have no idea how they work.  That said I would still like to know why this is happening.

Comment: I've seen that when a style isn't defined in the CSS. Could it be in a stylesheet you didn't import in the page header?

Comment: @Tim That's the weird part.  All three styles are in the same file yet some are fine sometimes.  I can see no pattern to when or why its happening.

Answer (score 0):

Does page 2 have a header with a link tag pointing to that stylesheet?  If css isn't being expressed it may because that specific page doesn't see it.  If that's the case, you may need to added a tag pointing to that stylesheet.

Something like:

```
<LINK href="special.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Or more like:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <LINK href="special.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: This isn't the case. If you read the question you can see how I say it is taking the CSS from the CSS file (how could it if there was no reference to it in the head tag), inserting it into the top of the ASPX page and then renaming the style.

Comment: I understood the question.  But I've run into this before and adding the direct reference has helped me in the past- which is why I mentioned this.

Comment: One of us is missing something here.  What do you mean by "direct" reference?